# ArcGIS Pro Display Filters not working?

Tags: sql, arcgis-pro, query

I love the new Display Filters feature in ArcGIS Pro. I've used them a few times and they're great! However, recently when I've tried to utilize them they don't seem to work anymore. Below is a screenshot of the settings I have and the data. The data is mileposts on a pipeline. I want to show only every tenth milepost on the first filter at a scale range of 1:50,000-1:5,000 (SQL query is (MRL_MEAS%1<>0)), every whole milepost on the second filter at a scale range of 1:100,000-1:50,000 (SQL query is (MRL_MEAS%1=0)), and only every milepost divisible by 10 on the third filter at a scale range of 1:20,000,000-1:100,000 (SQL query is (MRL_MEAS%10=0)). In the screenshot below I'm at a scale of 1:500,000, so only mileposts divisible by 10 should be shown, but ALL mileposts are being shown. I'm not sure what's going on, because I haven't had this issue before, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Any help?

[image]